# Extracting binary name from PDB file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, windbg, pdb-files

I am working on a project where I need to extract binary name information from a pdb(program database information) file. Earlier I thought that I will be able to do it as:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DiaSource),
                        NULL,
                        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                        __uuidof(IDiaDataSource),
                        (void **) ppSource);
hr = (*ppSource)->openSession(ppSession);

  hr = (*ppSession)->get_globalScope(ppGlobal);

  BSTR name;
  (*ppGlobal)->get_name(&name);
```

This is the snippet with very no error handling, I just realized that this will just yield information about the pdb filename and not binary name. Can anyone please suggest any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily expect the name of the binary to be in the PDB, so I'm not sure you're going to have much luck.